# How do I get the object to the ground floor grid?

Tags: coordinates

I have an object that is far away from the starting point grid. When I Add a Bezier Curve, it is on the grid and switch to Top view, it is too far away to see and manipulate. How do I get my object in the center of the grid so I can do the curve-the-object around the Curve trick?

Comment: and you add screen shots?

Comment: 'N' to bring up the properties panel and then set all the location fields X,Y,Z to 0 ?

Comment: @rob that works!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is difficult to locate the exact location of your object in the 3D editor.

You can directly set a number of properties for Meshes and other items in the Properties Panel.

[image]

The Properties Panel can be toggled with the 'n' key in any 3D view(and a number of other views).

To set the Location to 0 for X,Y,Z click and drag from the X input box to the Z so they are all highlighted. Then just type 0 to set them all to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

There is the simple way to do that without changing your object location.

Add an Empty object then make it follow the curve. 
After that, add a *Copy Transform* constrain to your object with target is the Empty object that you just created.